# Traduzione di 'jobs act'

Tags: translation, foreign-words

Presumo si sappia che governo italiano sta predisponendo il cosiddetto 'jobs act'.

Due domande:

- come si tradurrebbe in italiano 'jobs act' senza alterarne la sonorità epica che la lingua inglese gli conferisce?
- perchè 'jobs act' e non 'job act'?

Comment: Non ci ho riflettuto abbastanza da articolare una risposta, ma consiglio la lettura di http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2014/03/07/forestierismi-superflui-jobs-act/ 
Quanto alla seconda domanda, forse riecheggia il JOBS Act di Obama, dove JOBS sta per “Jumpstart Our Business Startups” (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumpstart_Our_Business_Startups_Act).

Comment: Piccolo aggiornamento: http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2014/03/12/definizione-jobs-act-ministero-lavoro/
Quindi in un certo senso la risposta al quesito originario è “piano del Governo per favorire il rilancio dell’occupazione e riformare il mercato del lavoro italiano”.

Comment: Job act, non jobs act! Il decreto sul lavoro, non il decreto sui lavori!

Comment: @Walid Alam: Non vuol dire nulla. In questo senso, lavoro è più inteso come nome collettivo, che raggruppa tutti i tipi di lavoro. Io rimarrei con "Jobs act" => "Riforma del lavoro".
Non avrebbe senso dire "riforma dei lavori", nè viene mai usato anche quando, in italiano, ci riferiamo ad una riforma che ha come oggetto più di una categoria lavorativa.

Comment: Qualche nuova riflessione sul fatto che non solo “Jobs act” non ha senso in italiano, ma non lo ha neppure per gli angolofoni: http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2014/11/24/traduzione-inglese-jobs-act/

Comment: Allora,visto che non si può alterare la sonorità,e, neanche la parola Jobs,perchè accidenti
non si può dire semplicemente "Riforma del lavoro 2014" cio

Answer (score 5):

Seguendo la stessa logica della riforma del 2003 - chiamata appunto "riforma del diritto societario", o semplicemente "riforma del 2003" - lo tradurrei con "Riforma del diritto del lavoro del 2014".

Answer (score 2):

se *io* dovessi rendere in italiano "Jobs act" (e notate che non ho scritto "tradurre"), cercherei un retronimo per LAVORO, qualcosa tipo Legge Aggiungente Valore Ottimale per la Realizzazione Occupazionale). Ovviamente nessuno si ricorderebbe dell'acronimo ma avrebbe questa lontana rimembranza dell'esistenza dell'acronimo stesso :-)

Comment: Sì, ma in questo modo sembra più un progetto dell'Unione Europea che una legge italiana...

Answer (score 2):

La traduzione corretta può essere "Legge sul lavoro" o "Legge sulle professioni".
Per mantenerne la sonorità potresti usare "Testo unico del lavoro" o, per avvicinarti agli obiettivi dichiarati, potresti usare "Testo unico di riforma del lavoro".

Concordo con DaG sul riferimento al [Jumpstart Our Business Startups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumpstart_Our_Business_Startups_Act) di Obama.

Answer (score 0):

`Jobs act` viene tradotto con `Piano per il lavoro` dal [Vocabolario Treccani.it](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/parole/delleconomia/Jobs_act.html).

Trovo però che il termine `decreto` sia molto più accattivante, anche perchè di un [decreto](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decreto) si tratta. Direi quindi `Decreto sul lavoro`.

Comment: ...“accattivante”?? Che intendi? Forse “appropriato”?

Comment: @DaG OP: `senza alterarne la sonorità epica che la lingua inglese gli conferisce`.